# Carousel with Android using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a horizontal scrolling carousel using a `RecyclerView`.

I'm trying to figure out how to set a width for each `RecyclerView` cell item, when using a `LinearLayoutManager` as it's `LayoutManager.`

I'd like to keep the "layout_width" property of each cell's layout to "match_parent" and have the "parent" be at max a certain number of DPs.

Right now, each cell occupies the entire width of the viewport. I'd like, instead to show 2.5 items or so across the width of the viewport.

How can I achieve this?

Basically, I'm looking for something similar to how `GridLayoutManager` automatically scales the width of the cells.

Is this possible in a simple manner?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: No I abandoned it unfortunately.